# Semicolon required in /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

Tags: wifi, raspbian-jessie, dhcp

Strange error occurs when I do either `ifdown wlan0` or `ifup wlan0`:

```
# ifdown wlan0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.1
Copyright 2004-2014 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf line 17: semicolon expected.
link-timeout 10;
              ^
/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf line 18: semicolon expected.
reboot 
 ^
```

What is wants if semicolons are there?

Entire file is like this:

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;
backoff-cutoff 2;
initial-interval 1;
link-timeout 10;
reboot 0;
retry 10;
select-timeout 0;
timeout 30;

send host-name = gethostname();
...
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Please try to edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: I described what I do and what is happeneing... What I missed?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can glean from the dhclient.conf documentation (https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhclient.conf), the command `link-timeout might not exist and be misinterpreted for something else, thus leading to these strange error messages.